# Can I export point cloud in three js to ply format?

Tags: javascript, three.js, point-clouds

I am using Three js to generate point cloud from depth image, but I'm not able to export this point cloud in ply format. Can someone help me, this is the code.

I tried to add it with the html of this from the library of three js to export in ply but I didn't have a good result.

Please Someone can help me.

```html
<canvas></canvas>

<style>
    body {
        margin: 0;
    }

    canvas {
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
        display: block;
    }
</style>
<script src="https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r94/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r94/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>

<script>
    'use strict';

    /* global THREE */

    function loadImage(url) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const img = new Image();
            img.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
            img.onload = (e) => { resolve(img); };
            img.onerror = reject;
            img.src = url;
        });
    }

    function getImageData(img) {
        const ctx = document.createElement("canvas").getContext("2d");
        ctx.canvas.width = img.width;
        ctx.canvas.height = img.height;
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        return ctx.getImageData(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
    }

    // return the pixel at UV coordinates (0 to 1) in 0 to 1 values
    function getPixel(imageData, u, v) {
        const x = u * (imageData.width - 1) | 0;
        const y = v * (imageData.height - 1) | 0;
        if (x < 0 || x >= imageData.width || y < 0 || y >= imageData.height) {
            return [0, 0, 0, 0];
        } else {
            const offset = (y * imageData.width + x) * 4;
            return Array.from(imageData.data.slice(offset, offset + 4)).map(v => v / 255);
        }
    }

    async function main() {
        const images = await Promise.all([
            loadImage("https://i.imgur.com/UKBsvV0.jpg"), // RGB
            loadImage("https://i.imgur.com/arPMCZl.jpg"), // Depth
        ]);
        const data = images.map(getImageData);

        const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
        const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ canvas: canvas });

        const fov = 75;
        const aspect = 2; // the canvas default
        const near = 1;
        const far = 4000;
        const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);
        camera.position.z = 2000;

        const controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, canvas);
        controls.target.set(0, 0, 0);
        controls.update();

        const scene = new THREE.Scene();

        const rgbData = data[0];
        const depthData = data[1];

        const skip = 20;
        const across = Math.ceil(rgbData.width / skip);
        const down = Math.ceil(rgbData.height / skip);

        const positions = [];
        const colors = [];
        const color = new THREE.Color();
        const spread = 1000;
        const depthSpread = 1000;
        const imageAspect = rgbData.width / rgbData.height;

        for (let y = 0; y < down; ++y) {
            const v = y / (down - 1); for (let x = 0; x < across; ++x) {
                const u = x /
                    (across - 1); const rgb = getPixel(rgbData, u, v); const depth = 1 - getPixel(depthData, u, v)[0];
                positions.push((u * 2 - 1) * spread * imageAspect, (v * -2 + 1) * spread, depth * depthSpread,);
                colors.push(...rgb.slice(0, 3));
            }
        } const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
        geometry.addAttribute('position', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(positions, 3));
        geometry.addAttribute('color', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(colors, 3));
        geometry.computeBoundingSphere(); const material = new THREE.PointsMaterial({
            size: 15, vertexColors:
                THREE.VertexColors
        }); const points = new THREE.Points(geometry, material); scene.add(points); function
            resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer) {
            const canvas = renderer.domElement; const
                width = canvas.clientWidth; const height = canvas.clientHeight; const needResize = canvas.width !== width ||
                    canvas.height !== height; if (needResize) { renderer.setSize(width, height, false); } return needResize;
        } function render(time) {
            time *= 0.001; if (resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer)) {
                const
                    canvas = renderer.domElement; camera.aspect = canvas.clientWidth / canvas.clientHeight;
                camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
            } renderer.render(scene, camera); requestAnimationFrame(render);
        }
        requestAnimationFrame(render);
    } main(); </script>
```

Comment: Have you considered to use [THREE.GLTFExporter](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#examples/en/exporters/GLTFExporter) to export your point cloud data? It's a more modern standard compared than PLY and the recommended 3D format of `three.js`.

Comment: @Mugen87 this is my difficult, i don't get export this code in another format